# Any open-source to animate 2D materials in 3D. (e.g. van der Waals heterostructures, 2D crystal layers etc.)

Tags: organic-chemistry, molecular-structure, crystallography

I want to model different 2D nano-structures, layered materials in 3D (animated version). Is there any open source where I can build these structures. Like this:

[image]

Comment: This would be better suited on [Matter Modelling SE](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: I agree, there are probably more experts over there. I'm hesitant though, because I don't think it is off topic here. If you choose to ask your question there, please delete it here. (It might have already been asked, too, so please check that before asking.) Cc @Safdar / To the matter at hand: I don't understand the animated aspect. The picture looks static to me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/467/which-are-the-freely-available-crystal-structure-visualization-softwares/470#470 Also: https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/1391/what-is-the-most-user-friendly-software-for-frequency-visualization-rendering/1392#1392